# How do we convert a date in format MMddyyyy to Mm/dd/yyyy using angular

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, validation, format

What is the best way to convert a date which is in format MMddyyyy to MM/day/year using angular 8 please suggest
Example : If user enters a date with format 08252020 it should be converted to 08/25/2020 if you have any working examples that would be great

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using "moment" package?
You can parse and then convert from any date format to any other

Comment: No I haven't used it our requirement was not to use moment or any package

Comment: If you know the exact format and it's just converting dates use something like 
const date = '05302020';
const year = date.substr(4);
const month = date.substr(0,2);
const day = date.substr(2,2);
const out = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;